# Space is expanding but the space around me isn't

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, matter

Everyone says space is expanding and distances between galaxies growing. But space isn't limited to outside of the earth. Space is everywhere on earth and around me. However I don't notice any expansion of the space around me? Is it because I am on Earth and the local space is affected by gravity?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2110/50583

Answer (score -1):

Well, technically it is still expanding, but gravity is still strong enough to hold the objects around you in place. Some scientists speculate that the universe will end when gravity is not strong enough to stop everything from expanding.

Comment: Citation?  Sources?